# error:-notication badge on action bar is not showing

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-view

I am new android.I want to develop an android app in which there is a notification badge on action bar.But the application is not starting.In my activity there is a list which is fetching from server and a dialog on click of list item. There is a null point exception at starting of application.Please guide to solve this error.I am referring this link for making notification badge:- [Notification Badge On Action Item Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43194243/notification-badge-on-action-item-android)

error:-

```
Process: com.example.chaitanya.yoga, PID: 4497
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.chaitanya.yoga.record.onCreateOptionsMenu(record.java:201)
                  at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2869)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:548)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:917)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:258)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5237)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:707)
```

record.class

```
public class record extends Activity {
.....
ArrayList<String> asd;
private ListView listView;
String info[];
String info1[];
String info2[];
String info3[];
String info4[];
String info5[];
static int abc;
int counter = 1;
TextView textCartItemCount;
int mCartItemCount = 10;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.record);

    asd = new ArrayList<String>();
    new gro().execute();
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    idName = prefs.getInt("idName", 0); 
    Intent intent = new Intent(record.this,
            BackgroundService.class);
    intent.putExtra("counter", counter++);
    startService(intent);
}


class gro extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        ...
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        .....
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {

        }
        return null;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();

        class ViewDialog {

            public void showDialog(Activity activity, int pos) {
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
                TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.nm1);
                TextView text1 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.rolln);
                TextView text2 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.bran);
                TextView text3 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.mobi);
                TextView text4 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.emai);
                TextView text5 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dobb);
                text.setText(info[pos]);
                text1.setText("RollNo: " + info1[asd.size() - pos - 1]);
                text2.setText("Branch: " + info2[asd.size() - pos - 1]);
                text3.setText("MobileNo: " + info3[asd.size() - pos - 1]);
                text4.setText("EmailId: " + info4[asd.size() - pos - 1]);
                text5.setText("DateOfBirth: " + info5[asd.size() - pos - 1]);


                Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_dialog);
                dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                dialog.show();

            }
        }


        ......

        Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(info));
        customList = new CustomList(record.this, info);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(customList);
        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                           int position, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ViewDialog alert = new ViewDialog();
                alert.showDialog(record.this, position);
                return false;
            }
        });

    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    final MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_cart);

    View actionView = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);
    textCartItemCount = (TextView) actionView.findViewById(R.id.cart_badge);
    setupBadge();

    actionView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
        }
    });

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.action_cart: {
            Toast.makeText(this, "item clickeddddd",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            textCartItemCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void setupBadge() {

    if (textCartItemCount != null) {
        if (mCartItemCount == 0) {
            if (textCartItemCount.getVisibility() != View.GONE) {
                textCartItemCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        } else {
            textCartItemCount.setText(String.valueOf(Math.min(mCartItemCount, 99)));
            if (textCartItemCount.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
                textCartItemCount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }

}
}
```

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.chaitanya.yoga" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
     >
    <activity android:name=".record" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <service
        android:name=".BackgroundService"
        android:enabled="true">
    </service>
</application>
```

menu_main.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <menu 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_cart"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:title="Cart"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/custom_action_item_layout"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
   </menu>
```

badge_background.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
 android:shape="oval">

<solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>
<stroke android:color="@android:color/white" android:width="1dp"/>

</shape>
```

record.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout    
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.chaitanya.yoga.record">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView" />
```

custom_action_item_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
style="?attr/actionButtonStyle"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:focusable="true">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cart_badge"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right|end|top"
    android:layout_marginEnd="-5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="-5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:background="@drawable/badge_background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:text="0"
    android:textSize="10sp"/>
```

Comment: Can you share `custom_action_item_layout`?

Comment: updated my description with custom_action_item_layout. @Mehmed

Comment: It works when I try. However, it seems `actionView` in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` is null in your case, can you verify that? If so, can you check that you are referencing correct id's in case of renaming issues? As a last resort, you can try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45418394/876267

Comment: I changed activity to appcompactactivity and it worked..

Comment: Nice to hear that, it is the only and most crucial difference that I missed...

Comment: Refer these will be helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43194243/notification-badge-on-action-item-android/43195893